Can I use CppUTest with QT Creator's libraries?
I want to use CppUTest in my project which I developed in QT Creator. but there are some problems like:
I can't test signal and slot because of meta-object compiler (moc) file.
Some functions (exp: qDebug()) detected as memoryLeak by CppUTest.
When I tested with QTest there no such problems, but I still want to use CppUTest. My project includes lot of QT's macros and libraries.do you have any ideas for solution?
I tried test without QT Framework's functions and QObjects' and it works well on c++ codes as I expected, but most of my test includes these components.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
